# Group dict elements based on a specified dict value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this data:

```
data = 
{
   "a":{
      "00066554466":{
         "Id":650,
         "Passwd":"e1c2a06545de9164d7e87cd98bed57c5",
         "zone":"Europe/Zurich"
      },
      "8745212300":{
         "Id":400,
         "Passwd":"ecb95502daace7f46bf12b484d086e5b",
         "zone":"Europe/Zurich"
      },
      "8745212301":{
         "Id":401,
         "Passwd":"ecb95502daace7f46bf12b484d086e5b",
         "zone":"Europe/Zurich"
      },
      "8745212302":{
         "DevId":402,
         "Passwd":"ecb95502daace7f46bf12b484d086e5b",
         "zone":"Europe/Zurich"
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to group keys with same Passwd. So result should be like the following.

```
{
   "e1c2a06545de9164d7e87cd98bed57c5":[
      "00066554466"
   ],
   "ecb95502daace7f46bf12b484d086e5b":[
      "8745212300",
      "8745212301",
      "8745212302"
   ]
}
```

I tried with itertools.groupby and with `for k,v in xxx`, but the result is never what I need.

Comment: Do you have more than one key in the outer dictionary? If yes, how does the rest of the data look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` works well when then data is already sorted with values to be grouped in a successive order, which might not always be the case with your data.

Rather use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) and a nested loop:

```
out = {}

for d1 in data.values():
    for k, d2 in d1.items():
        out.setdefault(d2['Passwd'], []).append(k)

print(out)
```

Variant with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)

for d1 in data.values():
    for k, d2 in d1.items():
        out[d2['Passwd']].append(k)

print(dict(out))
```

Output:

```
{'e1c2a06545de9164d7e87cd98bed57c5': ['00066554466'],
 'ecb95502daace7f46bf12b484d086e5b': ['8745212300', '8745212301', '8745212302']}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution, but probably not the pythonic is just to do:

```
passwd_group = {}

for k, val in data["a"]:

    if val["Passwd"] not in passwd_group:
        passwd_group[val["Passwd"]] = []

    passwd_group.append(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be ideal but got it working.

```
new_dict = {}
for L in data.keys():
    x = data[L]
    for M in x.keys():
        y = x[M]
        for N in y.keys():
            if N == "Passwd":
                new_list = new_dict.get(y[N], [])
                new_list.append(M)
                new_dict[y[N]] = new_list
print(new_dict)
```